# Xcode simulator build gives error, simulator does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, build

When I open the xcodeproj file of the project I just created and run the simulator, it gives the error in the image.

I ran the pod install command and it didn't work. I tried npm install, pod update commands and it didn't work. How can I fix?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csVTM.png)

Comment: Did you open the workspace that was created after doing 'pod install`? Never open the project file, always  open the workspace file when using Cocoapods.

Comment: There is a file named xcodeproj in the IOS folder. xcworkspace file does not exist. When I open this file and run the project in xcode, it gives an error. react-native run-ios command also gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pods file is either corrupt or missing.

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I just built the project from scratch everything was set up for the first time

Comment: Have you tried pod init?

Comment: @Kingsley Mitchell pod install command gives error during installation installation does not complete successfully
Screenshots;

https://prnt.sc/BhdjdLJM1pfK

https://prnt.sc/ewFYUw44kQpy

https://prnt.sc/ITvle8rb4ikJ

Comment: Save the pods text to another file and then delete the pod file, make a new one and remove glog, try again